# SignalR plus NancyFX : A simple but well worked example

Tags: signalr, nancy

There are a few examples of NancyFX being integrated with SignalR, for example

- [Signalr & Nancyfx integration](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13817794/776476)

Since I am just starting out I want a simple, well worked canonical example that I can work from. A nancy version of the chat example from Microsoft would do fine.

- [Tutorial: Getting Started with SignalR (C#)](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr)

Thanks

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I am going to answer my own question.

I put together a little canonical-chat example based on the Microsoft walkthrough. You can get it from GitHub:

- [Nancy + SignalR - Canonical Chat](https://github.com/biofractal/Nancy-SignalR-Canonical-Chat)

---

***Update***

This example has been updated to use the latest SignalR and NancyFX Assemblies as of February **2015**.

---

***ScreenShot***

[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

Comment: sure it took you long to create example :)

Comment: I wish this did't use coffee, just plain javascript.

Comment: @DonnyV. If you struggle with the coffeescript syntax you can always replace the ceremony using [js2coffee](http://js2.coffee/).

Comment: @biofractal I just realized it uses Microsoft.Owin. I'm looking for something that can be self hosted in Nancy and run on Mono. You don't happened to know of any examples do you?

Comment: @biofractal I am new to nancy and checked your code. There is no `UseNancy` in the `Startup` file. Where do you exactly add nancy to pipeline. All other examples I saw seems to use the `UseNancy` command.

Comment: But you don't explain what you did?  Did you create it with Nancy template, or start from a bare website? Which NUGET's did you add?  What special lines of code did you have to change for Nancy / for SignalR so they both work together?